# Which USA Politicians want to shut down the CIA?

Tags: united-states, human-rights, war-crime, cia

[Congressman Ron Paul wanted to shut down the CIA](https://www.fitsnews.com/2018/05/22/ron-paul-the-cia-is-the-problem/) for several reasons.

This intelligence agency has performed torture and terrorist-like actions all over the world since its creation.

Are there any other USA politicians who are for the idea of shutting down this agency?

Comment: John Kerry tried to defund the CIA after 9/11.  Trying to find a reference but coming up short.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bernie Sanders wanted to in [1974](https://www.politico.com/story/2016/02/bernie-sanders-cia-219451), but later retracted his position, urging instead for funding cuts and reining it in. During the 2016 Democratic Presidential Primary, Hillary Clinton and surrogates attacked this old position for its radicalism. From what I can find online, no politicians currently serving advocate the termination of the CIA.

Answer (score 8):

Famously the President that helped create it, Truman, did.  He told his biographer, [Merle Miller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0425094995)

> I think [creation of the CIA] was a mistake. And if I'd know what was going to happen, I never would have done it.
>
> Now, as nearly as I can make out, those fellows in the CIA don't just report on wars and the like, they go out and make their own, and there's nobody to keep track of what they're up to. They spend billions of dollars on stirring up trouble so they'll have something to report on. They've become ... it's become a government all of its own and all secret. They don't have to account to anybody.

In addition, Trump plans or hopes to reduce the size of the [CIA](http://www.businessinsider.com/trump-overhaul-top-intelligence-agencies-cia-dni-2017-1).  The WSJ article that broke the story is better but is behind a paywall.